# Enter param in inline javascript function

Tags: javascript

How can I add a param to the `removeSound` function in this JavaScript code?

I cannot get it to work.

```
var param = "111";

coder = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="javascript: removeSound(' + param + ');" >Delete</a>'
```

**Update**

I do not know why code = was removed! This is needed to explain the problem context.

Comment: I just need to know how to add a param to the function without breaking it. The function it self does not matter.

Comment: If it doesn't work with single quotes then your function is erroneous.

Comment: I have added that extra bit of information to my answer.

Comment: ah, are you trying to put a piece of html code into a variable called code/coder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to add a proper double quoting escape method to the answers as none showed a correct way to escape double quotes inside of an `onClick` attribute.

In HTML it is not sufficient to use only a backslash when escaping a JavaScript double quote. You need the proper HTML entity which is `&quot;`

This is a live example:

```
<a href="#" onClick="removeSound(&quot;121212&quot;);">Delete</a>
```

However for readability I would recommend using Antony Scott's way by using single quotes.

```
<a href="#" onClick="removeSound('121212');">Delete</a>
```

To add the param as a variable from whatever script your HTML is generated in you should do this:

```
code = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="javascript: removeSound(&quot;' + the_param + '&quot;);" >Delete</a>';
```

The other possible way should be:

```
code = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="javascript: removeSound(\'' + the_param + '\');" >Delete</a>';
```

Comment: Works fine! How can I add two params?

Comment: This really depends on the type. If it is of type `String` then you'd have to add a coma after the escaped single quote. If it is of any other type then you don't quote them at all and just separate them with a coma.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use different quotes. Try something like this ...

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="javascript: removeSound('PARAM HERE');" >Delete</a>
```

Comment: I have updated my question and example to better reflect what I needed to do.

Comment: did you want the 111 to be a string or a number within your removeSound function?

Comment: @JonathanClark Indeed, you gotta pay attention to that since all the methods we have shown you will have the parameter be a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
code = '<a href="#" onclick="removeSound("PARAM HERE");">Delete</a>';
```

Comment: I have updated my question and example to better reflect what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <a href="#" onClick="removeSound('121212')" >Delete</a>
```

Comment: I have updated my question and example to better reflect what I needed to do.